# Create instance of IndexName in NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm trying to create a new index in ElasticSearch using NEST, this new index has aliases, so I need an instance of IndexName in order to achieve this. This is the request I'm trying to implement:

```
PUT activeIndexName
{
    "aliases": {
        "indexName": {}
    }
}
```

My code in NEST:

```
    public bool CreateIndex(string indexName)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string activeIndexName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-000001", indexName, date);
        IDictionary<IndexName, IAlias> aliasDict = new Dictionary<IndexName, IAlias>();
        IndexName indexNameDict = IndexName.From<IndexName>(indexName);//PROBLEM HERE
        
        aliasDict.Add(indexNameDict, new Alias());


        CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(activeIndexName)
        {
            Aliases = new Aliases(aliasDict)
        };

        CreateIndexResponse response = _client.Indices.Create(createIndexRequest);
        return response.IsValid;
    }
```

And the error message I'm getting from the above code:

```
Index name is null for the given type and no default index is set. Map an index name using ConnectionSettings.DefaultMappingFor<TDocument>() or set a default index using ConnectionSettings.DefaultIndex().
```

It sounds to me as if the index needs to be there before it can be created? However it needs to be created with an Alias. Nest.IndexName doesn't have a constructor so I'm not sure how to have an instance of it so that the Dictionary<IndexName, IAlias> can be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexName` [implements an implicit conversion from](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7.9/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/Infer/IndexName/IndexName.cs#L85) `string` so you can simplify and fix your code by replacing

```
IndexName indexNameDict = IndexName.From<IndexName>(indexName);//PROBLEM HERE
aliasDict.Add(indexNameDict, new Alias());
```

with

```
aliasDict.Add(indexName, new Alias());
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Aliases` implements `IEnumerable<IndexName, IAlias>` and an `Add(IndexName, IAlias)` method, so a collection initializer can be used to shorten the code to

```cs
public bool CreateIndex(string indexName)
{
    string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string activeIndexName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-000001", indexName, date);
    CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(activeIndexName)
    {
        Aliases = new Aliases
        {
            { indexName, new Alias() }
        }
    };

    CreateIndexResponse response = _client.Indices.Create(createIndexRequest);
    return response.IsValid;
}
```